# RangeError (start): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a new list from the current list in a project I am working on and I used the sublist () method while doing this, but I got the same error even if I tried other methods, can you please help me with this. And when I press the refresh button the error disappears, but it gives this error every time the application is opened. Here is my sample code:

```
class DeviceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DeviceScreen({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothDevice device;

  List<Widget> _buildServiceTiles(List<BluetoothService> services) {
    return services
        .map(
          (s) => ServiceTile(
            service: s,
            characteristicTiles: s.characteristics
                .map(
                  (c) => CharacteristicTile(
                    characteristic: c,
                    onReadPressed: () => c.read(),
                    onWritePressed: () async {
                      await c.write([49]);
                    },
                    onWritePressed2: () async {
                      await c.write([48]);
                    },
                    onNotificationPressed: () =>
                        c.setNotifyValue(!c.isNotifying),
                    descriptorTiles: c.descriptors
                        .map(
                          (d) => DescriptorTile(
                            descriptor: d,
                            onReadPressed: () => d.read(),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }

            StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothService>>(
              stream: device.services,
              initialData: [],
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                return Column(
                  children: _buildServiceTiles(snapshot.data).sublist(1),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Error image:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the error as well?

Comment: When I press the refresh button the error disappears, but it gives this error every time the application is opened.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when you try to access an index of the list which exceeds the length of the list. (If the max length of list is 3 (0,1,2) and you try to access index 10).

I am guessing the error is caused at the _buildServiceTiles() function in the StreamBuilder Widget. Here you are passing the index 1 everytime but the above error will be caused when that function returns an empty list.

**Solution :**
Add a handler for empty list like

```
(snapshot.data).length == 0 ? /*Some other function*/ :_buildServiceTiles(snapshot.data).sublist(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your return. Actually, there are 2 element in my main list, I want to reach the second of these element, but I get an error while doing this and when I try your solution, step the following error: "The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length"

Comment: This is common while using a StreamBuilder.. See when you first build a stream it wont necessarily provide you the required object. Usually it inititally returns a null value which is throwing that error as you cant get length of null object. For this, in your build function you can add another handler like snaphot.data == null ? /*return something like a text like loading.... or sometihng : return Column(......);